# how can I add a 3s fade-in and 3s fade-out to my Naudio waveoutform?

Tags: wpf

I want to add 3s fade-in, 60s of play and then a 3s fade-out to my song at waveOut.Play();

I have found that some fades can be added using waveout.Init(), but how to add two of them?

Here is the sample code I have tried

```
// Two seconds fade
    var fadeOut = new DelayFadeOutSampleProvider(sampleSource);
    fadeOut.BeginFadeOut(8000, 2000);

        // Here the fade is played exactly where expected (@00:08)
        var player = new WaveOut();
        player.Init(fadeOut);
        player.Play();
```

below is my code:

```
    try
    {
    
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async (o) =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => outputTextBox.Text = "3"));
            
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => outputTextBox.Text = "2"));
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => outputTextBox.Text = "1"));
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        });
    
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    
        if (waveOut!=null ) waveOut.Stop(); 
    
        Songs = db.Songs; 
        int r = rnd.Next(Songs.Count);
    
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(r);
    
        String name = ((Song)Songs[r]).Name1;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(name);
    
        int start = ((Song)Songs[r]).Start1;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(start);
    
        waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
        
    
        var ms = File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\Wellumies\\source\\repos\\SquareDance\\Data\\music\\"+name);
        var rdr = new Mp3FileReader(ms);
        var wavStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(rdr);
        wavStream.Skip(start);
        var baStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(wavStream);
        
        waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
        
            waveOut.Init(baStream);
    
        
        
        waveOut.Play();
```